# На сайте отображаются куки с другого домена

Tags: node.js, сервер, cookie, клиент-сервер

У меня сервер на node.js. На нём я использую API вконтакте. С клиента приходит запрос `/find_user` методом post и с переданным аргументом `id`. На сервере отправляется запрос к API вконтакте, а полученный результат отправляется на клиент. На клиенте обнаружил, что вкладка с куками отображает все куки с домена вконтакте.

Вот эти:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не то, чтобы они сильно мешали, но несколько смущает их появление. Как, почему, зачем?

Comment: Просто хром показывает  куки со всех доменов к которым были запросы с этой страницы. Это вовсе не значит что эти куки появились у вас или что вы можете получить к ним доступ.

Comment: @AlexeyTen вопрос и заключается в том, что я не понимаю, как хром понимает, что сервер отправил запрос к API вконтакте. Сама страница в браузере запросов к ВК не делает.

Comment: Точно не отправляет? Даже за картинками, например?

Comment: @AlexeyTen за картинками отправляет, действительно. Тогда понял, спасибо.